# Select only the property names of a JSON object with ng-options

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, ng-options

I have a JSON object in my scope as follows:

```
$scope.props =
{
    'prop1': { 'att': 10 },
    'prop2': { 'att': 20 },
    ...
    'propN': { 'att': 42 }
};
```

I bind this object to a `select` using `ng-options`:

```
<select ng-options="propName for (propName,propVal) in props"
        ng-model="selectedProp"></select>
```

The options `prop1`, `prop2`, etc. show up in the drop-down box. When I select one of these options, the `propVal` is stored in `selectedProp`.

However, I need to store the actual property **name**, not its value. I can completely ignore the value - all I need is the selected property name string, such as "prop2".

Is this possible in AngularJS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
<select ng-options="key as key for (key , value) in props"
        ng-model="selectedProp"></select>
```

You can find more info in [angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select), but basically `key as key` refers at `value_to_store as value_to_display`. So you want to store in the model the property name (key) of the selected object and display it as that same property name.

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
<select ng-model="selectedProp" 

     ng-options="myProp.propName as myProp.propName for myProp in props">
```

Comment: `myProp` does not have a `propName`. I need the key "prop1".